# haversine formula returns no rows mysql when the values are same - nearest location

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the formula below in mysql,It works fine if the values are not same but if the values are same I do not get any values of the location I am standing on which happens to be the exact float value lat/lng. should I get `0` as that would mean nearest is where I am standing too.I really appreciate any Help .Thanks in Advance :

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: "... but if the values are the same I get `Null`" - which values? Note that if either of your `lat` or `lng` columns are null the result will be null.

Comment: If I have values in datatable where I am fetching lat/lng=37,-122 .I get no response - `sorry for not checking again`.If the values are 37.1.Then I get some distance .But I am supposed to get the value of diatance`0` also right which means I am standing on one Of the location.

Comment: Do you mean you're querying `WHERE lat = 37 AND lng = -122`? If so, then if there are no rows that satisfy the condition you won't get a zero. What you'll get is no results.

Comment: @EdGibbs Sorry I updated the Q.

Comment: @EdGibbs Exactly I get no rows .I should get the row which has the same value right ? with distance `0.00000000`something like that

Comment: @EdGibbs How do I work that out ?I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Please post the exact values in your database for the troublesome row (so we can try to replicate your problem)

Comment: Yes - please do as @bohemian asks. Or you could set it up on SQLFiddle and provide a link. I just set up a `markers` table here with columns `lat` and `lng` as `float` types. I added a row with `lat=37` and `lng=-122`, ran your query, and I got back a zero, which I think is what you're trying to get.

Comment: @EdGibbs I am sorry I tried that also and yes thats  right you get `0` for that .I am using values in `varchar` now I changed to `float 10,6` its working fine now .Thanks again.I really appreciate your time